# XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:8585/pay due to access control checks

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am using nodeJS and expressJS for backend and ReactJS for frontend of my application. Everything works fine when run locally on my computer. However, I recently have tried to deploy the app using Firebase. The app successfully launches at the given link from firebase.
The wired things happened.

1. It only works on my desktop's browsers.If I try to run my web site in other devices, it does not work. First, on desktop, in Chrome it works. In Safari, not working. In console, it shows 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8585/pay due to access control checks.'
   I search about it. I make a https localhost to fix the issue. Now on my desktop chrome and safari both work!!! Unfortunately, when I run the site on other devices. It never work!
2. However, when I check my site on my phone, chrome and safari not work for my site. I check the console it gave me

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:8585/pay due to access control checks.
```

I have been searching for it for a couple of days. I don't know why it only works on my desktop not other devices.
I have app.use(cors());to fix the access-control-allow-origin problem. I have no idea what is going on.

This is my index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_51HJ0tkCo200wpjbfBGB');
var path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs')
var https = require('https')
var certOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./server.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./server.crt'))
}

const port = 8585
app.use(cors());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))


// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello from the API")
})

app.post('/pay', async (req, res) => {
    const {amount, billingDetails} = req.body;
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      email: billingDetails.email,
      name: billingDetails.name,
      phone: 333333,
     
    });

    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: amount,
        currency: 'usd',
        customer: customer.id,
        // Verify your integration in this guide by including this parameter
        metadata: {integration_check: 'accept_a_payment'},
        receipt_email: billingDetails.email,
        description: `Purchased the ${billingDetails.name}`,
        shipping: {
          name: billingDetails.name,
          address: {
            line1: billingDetails.address.line1,
            city: billingDetails.address.city,
            country: billingDetails.address.country,
            postal_code: billingDetails.address.postal_code
          }
        }
      });

      res.json({'client_secret': paymentIntent['client_secret']})
})


https.createServer(certOptions, app).listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}! https://localhost:${port}`))

//app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}! https://localhost:${port}`))
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

In my react, I make a post.

```
const res = await axios.post('https://localhost:8585/pay', {
        amount: (props.totalPrice*100).toFixed(0), 
        billingDetails: billingDetails,
        });
```

In my firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/api",
        "function": "api"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I already tried to make the post request like this

```
const res = await axios.post('/pay'
```

or

```
const res = await axios.post('/api/pay'
```

It gave me

```
the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

Thus, it does not works. Please help me out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to change *localhost* to your firebase ip